# ActionFilterAttribute equivalent in REST WCF .net 4.0

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.0

what is the `ActionFilterAttribute` equivalent in `WCF`?

I have a REST service which looks like below

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/")]
public User CreateBookMark(BookMark bm)
{
  User authenticateUser = GetUserSomeHow();

  //do stuff

}
```

I want to change this to following

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/")]
public User CreateBookMark(BookMark bm, User authenticateUser)
{

  //do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom service behavior (IServiceBehavior) - that hooks up a custom operation behavior (IOperationBehavior) that will inject the the extra parameter. It may be you also want to implement your own AuthorizationManager - but it's most likely that you can do with the features (OperationContext.Current.SecurityContext and System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal).

Comment: Do you have an example of how you would do it?